# How to count and combine two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query to do a combination and count. sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt. The individual queries sometimes dont equal each other. Anything am doing wrong here? Is there a better/easier way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT   CONVERT(VarChar(8), End_Date, 112)as End_Date,count(*) as Qty, 'LPFG' as     Wc_Code 
FROM
(
 (SELECT  dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr, Demand_Order_Line_Nbr,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), min(dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Row_Insert_Datetime), 112) as     End_Date
FROM dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event INNER JOIN dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order ON    (dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.MMM_Facility_Code = dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order.MMM_Facility_Code) AND (dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr = dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order.Demand_Order_Nbr)
WHERE (((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.MMM_Facility_Code)='MC') 
AND ((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Event_Type_Code)='Allocate') 
AND dimdbmc.dbo.t_demand_order.demand_order_type_code IN  ( 'COMS-SMPNO') 
AND ((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Row_Insert_Datetime)>= '8/01/2012'))
Group by
dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr,    dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Line_Nbr)
 UNION ALL

(SELECT  dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr, Demand_Order_Line_Nbr,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), min(dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Row_Insert_Datetime), 112) as    End_Date
FROM dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event INNER JOIN dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order ON    (dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.MMM_Facility_Code = dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order.MMM_Facility_Code) AND (dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr = dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order.Demand_Order_Nbr)
WHERE (((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.MMM_Facility_Code)='MC') 
AND ((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr) Is Not Null) 
AND ((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Event_Type_Code)='Allocate') 
AND substring(dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order.Demand_Order_Nbr, 8, 1) <>'_'  
AND dimdbmc.dbo.t_demand_order.demand_order_type_code IN  ( 'COMS-CUST','COMS-   GOVT','COMS-INTL') 
AND ((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Demand_Order.Charge_To_Customer_Nbr)='WHP4101')
AND ((dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Row_Insert_Datetime)>= '8/01/2012'))
Group by
dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Nbr,dimdbmc.dbo.t_Allocation_Event.Demand_Order_Line_Nbr
)

)as a

 group by End_Date
order by End_Date
```

Comment: This is a very specific question. Can you break it down into a simpler, more common version?

Comment: To help others help you, please consider to provide all relevant DDL, sample data (hopefully in a form of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)) and desired output